# Move order summary in checkout pages only in mobile so that it is always displayed

Tags: magento2.4, order-summary, mobile-menu

In mobile, or small-width devices, the order summary collapses to a burger menu. This isn't readily evident and I'd like to have the summary always displayed at the bottom of the main content i.e. after shipping or payment details. I know I can move the summary block but I don't want to change the behavior in desktop or larger screens when it displays on the right sidebar. I'm new to magento and it seems my only recourse is to do it in css or js? Is it possible at all without impacting other screen sizes?

Answer (score 1):

**Magento2 Show the Order summary in Mobile**

Please find the following path

vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/sidebar.html

and this file shows the following code

**sidebar.html**

```
<div id="opc-sidebar"
     data-bind="afterRender:setModalElement, mageInit: {
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal':{
        'type': 'custom',
        'modalClass': 'opc-sidebar opc-summary-wrapper',
        'wrapperClass': 'checkout-container',
        'parentModalClass': '_has-modal-custom',
        'responsive': true,
        'responsiveClass': 'custom-slide',
        'overlayClass': 'modal-custom-overlay',
        'buttons': []
    }}">

    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('summary') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!--/ko-->

    <div class="opc-block-shipping-information">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('shipping-information') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
    </div>
</div>
```

and this file remove this code **'responsiveClass': 'custom-slide'** ,

Run the below command

php bin/magento s:s:d -f &&
php bin/magento c:f &&
chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated

Another way remove only class name : **custom-slide**

Answer (score 0):

I think you need only set the 'resonsive' to "false" in the same file that "Mehul Dhapa" mean **"vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/sidebar.html"**.

```
 'parentModalClass': '_has-modal-custom',
 'responsive': false,
 'responsiveClass': 'custom-slide',
```